# Add videos to map on website

Tags: google-maps, video

Output: add videos and photos to map on personal website

What I have till now: successfully added a map without any functionality to my website

Question: How do I add those videos and photos to my map on my website?

Answer (score 0):

You can use embed function to call a video but it will be under the map. You can fix that using the `z-index` CSS property on the video.

Comment: There is an answer there. The question part should be edited out and moved to a comment on the question.

Comment: my video is going to be a simple youtube video..i want to be able to attach a video to a specific region of my map on my website

Comment: i don't know if this is possible..only image is i know..simply use marker and set the icon into the image path and name